# Question about Distributional Derivative of Monotonically Non-decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Suppose $f \geq 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ be monotonically non-decreasing. Let $T_f$ be the distribution given by $f$. Then, $T_f \geq 0$ for all $\psi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\psi(x) \geq 0$ on its support.

Is it then true that $T'_f$ is also a positive distribution?

As a side question, how does one prove that a function has distributional derivative given by a measure if $T_f$ is not positive? Is it possible for $T'_f$ to be given by a measure if $T'_f$ is not positive?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $T_f \geq 0$? As you have it, I disagree that $T_f \psi \geq 0$ for all $\psi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$; however, I do agree if we restrict to $\psi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with $\psi \geq 0$, as I suspect you intended.

Comment: @JonWarneke Indeed I did intend this.

Comment: How is $T_f'$ not positive if $f = x$: $T_x'(\phi) = \int x(-\phi') dx= \int \phi dx \ge 0$ if $\phi \ge 0$.

Comment: @JohnMa Shoot, I relegated the negative sign to the wrong part of the expression; I'd been thinking too much about the equation for the weak derivative and flipped the sign wrong, apologies... is it then true that $T'_f$ will always be positive?

Comment: @JohnMa I'm working on a problem that says if $f$ is m.n.d., then it's distributional derivative is a borel measure, and I've been trying to use the fact that if we split up $f$ into positive and negative parts and use the fact that if $T'_f$ is positive, it is given by a borel measure

Comment: @JohnMa Though the problem only says "borel measure" while if a distribution is positive we get a "regular borel measure", so I fear this might not be the right approach

Answer (score 1):

The question can actually be answered in the context of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals: Note that we have the following integration by part formula, when $f$ is nondecreasing and $\phi$ is of bounded variations:

$$\int_a^b f d\phi = f(b)\phi(b) - f(a)\phi(a) - \int_a^b \phi df.$$

we choose $a, b$ large enough so that $\phi(a) = \phi(b) = 0$. Thus

$$T_f'(\phi) = -\int  f \phi'dx = -\int f d\phi  = \int \phi df.$$

Since $f$ is nondecreasing, $T_f'$ is positive.

Comment: Does this then prove the problem statement?

Comment: Yes, @AnthonyPeter it proves that $T_f'$ is a positive distribution. I am still thinking about the Borel measurability though. The laziest way is to show that $\phi \mapsto \int \phi df$ is a bounded linear functional, thus $df$ is a Radon measure.

Comment: On notation, what is $df$?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter : That's [Riemann-Stieltjes_integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)

Comment: In other words, the measure given by $f$ since $f$ is m.n.d.?

Comment: Since $f$ is m.n.d., if you check the definition of $\int \phi df$, you see that $\int \phi df \ge 0$ if $\phi \ge 0$. @AnthonyPeter

Comment: will it always be true it is bounded? is this the easiest way to show it is a radon measure?

Comment: One can check that  $\left| \int \phi df\right| \le \int |\phi| df \le \sup |\phi| \int_a^b df = (f(b) -f(a)) \sup |\phi|$, where $\phi$ is supported in $[a,b]$. @AnthonyPeter I am not sure if it is the easiest way, still thinking.

Comment: I mean, if that's all why find something even simpler?

Comment: Well, the use of Riesz representation here just seems to be an overkill to me. @AnthonyPeter

Comment: Ah yes I agree, but it's available for use for the problem. The problem appears in ch 6 of Lieb Loss Analysis, after Riesz. But if you find another way, do tell. Like I said, I was suspicious since the problem only asked to find a borel measure, not a regular borel measure